# How to force three pages of a particular master at the beginning?

Tags: xsl-fo

I need this order at the beginning of every part in the book:

1. Right page without page number (with the title of the part).
2. Left blank page.
3. Right page without page number (first page of the subsequent chapter).
4. The rest is numbered.

If I am working only with chapters without parent parts, this works perfectly:

```
<fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
    <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="PageMaster.Blank" blank-or-not-blank="blank"/>
    <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="PageMaster.Page-Right.First" odd-or-even="odd" page-position="first"/>
    <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="PageMaster.Page-Left" odd-or-even="even"/>
    <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="PageMaster.Page-Right" odd-or-even="odd"/>
</fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
```

Typically, every part has its own title, no more. And I want the title to be on a separate right–sided page, like the first page of every chapter.

With the example above, everything works except the first page of every subsequent chapter is numbered.

Comment: Do you restart an `fo:page-sequence` for each new chapter?

Comment: Actually, yes in the case when I am working with chapters only. No in the case I need to work with parts + chapter. I am not sure how to do that because part is parent of chapters.

Comment: I think you need start a page-sequence for the part and the contents of the part - except the chapters. Then for each chapter, you'll create an new page-sequence like you already do. This is because you can tell you don't want page numbers for the first page of a page-sequence - and it's not possible in the middle of this page-sequence...

Comment: Well, I have just done some tests and still can't achieve that. The problem is I need to use only one flow per page sequence and here it seems I need something like nested sequences, which is, of course, nonsense :)

Comment: 1) Can you add your template for producing `part` title pages so we can see if anything can be done? 2) No, not nonsense: https://www.antennahouse.com/product/ahf63/ahf-ext.html#fo.page-sequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use three `fo:single-page-master-reference` -- for the part title, the blank next page, and the chapter title page -- followed by the `fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives` for blank, left, and right pages.